# Spark on AWS EMR: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Product.$init$(Lscala/Product;)V

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I'm trying to deploy a Scala 2.12.0 + Spark 2.4.4 application to AWS EMR.
I have Spark 2.4.4 enabled in EMR.

When the application runs, it fails with the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Product.$init$(Lscala/Product;)V
```

I'm building the jar using the "sbt-assembly" plugin. I specifically remove "org/apache/spark/" from the assembled jar to ensure no conflict in versions.

Answer (score 5):

While Spark 2.4.4 supposedly supports Scala 2.12.x, EMR doesn't seem to support it.

Instead, one must build using Scala 2.11.

E.g. in the build.sbt file:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.12"
```

Comment: Were you using EMR 5.29?

Comment: Actually I am able to make things work with Scala 2.12 on EMR 5.29 and Spark 2.4.4 BUT if I include Scallop (even for Scala 2.12) then I get the error you're describing and since we are sticking to scallop for now, I had to shift to Scala 2.11.12 to make things work. Hope this helps someone else coming to this page.